# If $x^2$ + $y^2$ = $11xy$, prove that $\log(x - y) = \frac{1}{2}\log x$ + $\frac{1}{2}\log y$ + $\log 3$. .

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x^2$ + $y^2$ = $11xy$, prove that $\log(x - y) = \frac{1}{2}\log x$ + $\frac{1}{2}\log y$ + $\log 3$.

I don't even know where to begin, this is the first time I have encountered a problem like this, please guide me through this proof. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: subtract $2xy$ from both sides

Comment: Thank you, I feel so dumb right now, I hope I can improve my intuition.

Comment: $lg$ is not a common usage, prefer $\ln$ or $\log$ or $\log_2$, at least the notation needs to be explicited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2+y^2=11xy$ can be written as $x^2+y^2-2xy=9xy\Longrightarrow(x-y)^2=9xy$ or $x-y=3\sqrt x\sqrt y$. Apply log on both sides, you get your result.

Comment: Thank you, I feel so dumb right now, I hope I can improve my intuition. The problem was so simple yet I got scared and lost all hope and gave up easily.